# Как написать новую библиотеку Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть старая нереляционная СУБД Oracle Codasyl DBMS, для которой нет готовой библиотеки Entity Framework. Хоть она и не реляционная, но с принципами EF кажется вполне совместимой.  Каким должен быть план действий, чтобы написать новую библиотеку? Понятно, что проект такого рода следует делать открытым и вести на GitHub или (что вряд ли) на другой платформе.

[Тут (docs.microsoft.com)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/writing-an-ef-data-provider) написано, что можно это сделать, используя ADO.Net провайдер.

Но готового ADO.Net провайдера для этой СУБД тоже нет. Также судя по всему, мануал ориентирован на SQL-СУБД.

Реализуема ли в таком случае библиотека для такой СУБД? Может кто-то описать, какой порядок действий для нереляционной СУБД без готового провайдера?

Comment: Откройте готовый (для другой субд), посмотрите как сделан. Студия показывает "наследование" в готовом классе. Вам нужно наследовать базовые библиотеки Entity

Comment: Я предлагаю этого не делать. Причины: EF - это громоздкое решение, оптимизированное для работы с MS SQL. Для эффективной работы тебе придётся написать свой собственный EF, при этом загнав всё это в рамки интерфейсов EF, большая часть которых, подозреваю, тебе не нужны. Если же очень хочется, то я бы взял за основу Oracle.ManagedDataAccess и переписал его для работы с твоей базой. Но цена разработки будет выше стоимости перехода на новую БД (диванное мнение).

Comment: >>нереляционная СУБД Oracle Codasyl DBMS, для которой нет готовой библиотеки<< А что на этот счёт говорит хибер? Личное ИМХО, когда столкнулся с EF (в частности EF6), обнаружил для себя неприятные моменты, которые попросту отсутствовали в Hibernate. Я не имею ничего против EF, но, чистое ИМХО, для смены БД в разы лучше подходит именно хибер, где заменить БД можно, буквально, на горячую, не меняя ни строчки кода в проекте. В EF присутствуют системные механизмы, которые не дают такой свободы. Появляются всякие "миграции", которые лично мне, не понятны.

Comment: @LunarWhisper Oracle.ManagedDataAccess есть исходники?

Comment: @test123 На самом деле на эту СУБД нет вообще ничего. Т.к. её давно похоронили, а то что я ей интересуюсь, на это есть две причины. 1) Я с ней всё ещё работаю 2) Очень нравится её модель, кажется странным, что её похоронили, но спустя годы создали новый пласт NoSQL СУБД.